# How can I JOIN 3 tables in a single query

Tags: sql

My User table is

```
user_id | user_email | user_fname | user_lname | company_id | company_name
709149  | 709149@..  | train      | live       | 51472      | 
 70914  | 70914@..   | enthusiast | accessible | 13394      |
```

My Visit table is

```
visit_id | user_id | user_name | company_name | store_id | visit_in | ...
30594509 | 709149  | train live| xyz          | 15673    | 2019-09-09 16:26
30594506 | 709149  | train live| xyz          | 15673    | 2019-09-09 15:17
```

My user_store table is

```
user_id | store_id | 
709149  | 15673    |
709149  | 15674    |
709149  | 12230    |
```

The output table I desire is

```
user_fullname | user_id | company_name | last_visit 
train live    | 709149  | xyz          | 2019-09-09 15:17
```

Working query that gives records for multiple store_id

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_fname, ' ', user_lname) as user_fullname, u.user_id as user_id, IFNULL(c.company_name,u.company_name) AS 'company_name' , visit_in as last_visit 
            FROM user u
            JOIN user_store us ON u.user_id = us.user_id
            JOIN visit v ON u.user_id = v.user_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN company c ON u.company_id = c.company_id
```

Whereas I want to display only those records whose visit.store_id = user_store.store_id but I am unable to perform a JOIN.

I tried it like this in the above SQL query but didn't get the desired result.

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_fname, ' ', user_lname) as user_fullname, u.user_id as user_id, IFNULL(c.company_name,u.company_name) AS 'company_name' , visit_in as last_visit 
            FROM visit v , user u
            JOIN user_store us ON u.user_id = us.user_id
            JOIN user_store us ON v.store_id = us.store_id
            JOIN visit v ON u.user_id = v.user_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN company c ON u.company_id = c.company_id;
```

Comment: is this SQL Server? Or mySQL? Or even something else? That's a basic detail you need to tell us, to begin with.

Comment: Secondly it would be extremely useful to see some sample data, and the desired results of running your intended query on that data (not just the column headings). Then we can better understand the relationships etc.

Comment: At a guess, maybe take your first query and change `JOIN visit v ON u.user_id = v.user_id` to `JOIN visit v ON u.user_id = v.user_id AND v.store_id = us.store_id` . TBH though it's a bit unclear what the role of the user_store table is in representing your users' visits to stores. But without you explaining fully what the tables represent, and showing us sample data etc it's going to be hard to be sure what the real solution is.

Answer (score 2):

Your visit table has companyid as well hence you see redundant data add companyid/name in join condition as well

```
    ... JOIN visit v ON u.user_id = 
      v.user_id and u.companyname=
       v.companyname


     SELECT distinct 
     CONCAT(user_fname, ' ', user_lname) 
    as user_fullname, u.user_id as 
     user_id,  IFNULL
 (c.company_name,u.company_name) 
   AS 'company_name' , min(visit_in) as 
    last_visit 
        FROM user u
        JOIN user_store us ON u.user_id = 
         us.user_id
        JOIN visit v ON u.user_id = v.user_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN company c ON 
       u.company_id = c.company_id
```

Comment: Updated though that posted answer was already self explanatory if you could remove negative vote if that helps now

Comment: Agreed. The query seems unclear hence can understand

Comment: Use group by with min(visitin) as you have 2 visits for smae userid and store id. user_id | store_id | 
709149  | 15673    | has 2 records matching for 2 visits or use distinct with min/max on last visit in

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Got the desired answer. Thanks for helping out buddy